# How to display only selected data from database in Android Studio

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

My program is designed to search the database for the specific name entered, then the program will only display the row of the specific name. However, my code is  unable to display the specific data. I have tried many kind of ways but it is unable to solve my problem. My php code is as below:

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect('mysql17.000webhost.com', 'a2634311_minzhe', 'MZRules0118');

    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("a2634311_gdp", $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM groupdesign");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
      {
        $output[]=$row;
      }
    print(json_encode($output));

    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

My activity code is as below:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.StrictMode;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.InputStream;


    public class PatientLocation extends ActionBarActivity {

        private ListView PatientLocationListView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new         StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            this.PatientLocationListView = (ListView)         this.findViewById(R.id.listView4);

            new Location().execute(new API_Connector());
        }

        public void setListAdapter(JSONArray jsonArray) {

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("myprefrences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String name = settings.getString("name", "");
            this.PatientLocationListView.setAdapter(new         PatientAdapter(jsonArray,name, this));
        }

        private class Location extends AsyncTask<API_Connector, Long, JSONArray> {
            @Override
            protected JSONArray doInBackground(API_Connector... params) {

                //it is executed on Background thread

                return params[0].GetPatientLocation();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                // check for null
                if (jsonArray != null) {
                    // only pass the array to adapter if it is not null
                    setListAdapter(jsonArray);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(PatientLocation.this, "Null Array returned", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        }
    }

    class PatientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private JSONArray dataArray;
        private Activity activity;
        String pname;

        private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

        public PatientAdapter(JSONArray jsonArray, String name, Activity a) {
            this.dataArray = jsonArray;
            this.activity = a;
            this.pname = name;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater)         this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.dataArray.length();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            String patientname,patientlocation;
            //set up convert view if it is null
            ListCell cell = new ListCell();
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_position, null);

                cell.patient_name = (TextView)         convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView30);
                cell.patient_location = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView31);
                convertView.setTag(cell);
            }
            else {
                cell = (ListCell) convertView.getTag();
            }
            //change the data of the cell

            try {
                for(int i=0;i<dataArray.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = this.dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(pname == jsonObject.getString("Name")) {
                        patientname = jsonObject.getString("Name");
                        patientlocation = jsonObject.getString("Location");

                        cell.patient_name.setText(patientname);
                        cell.patient_location.setText(patientlocation);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return convertView;
        }

        private class ListCell {
            private TextView patient_name;
            private TextView patient_location;
        }

    }
```

Comment: When using `AsyncTask ` then no need to use `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy` method and are you getting data from server?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. Yes, I'm getting the data from server

Comment: It seems that in the View class, when i remove the if case, it will display all the data from server. However, with the if case, it is unable to display anything.

Comment: your question is not clear tell more about what problem getting currently

Comment: My code is to only display the data if the name from the database is equal.

Comment: Where is WHERE clause in your query in php code? You need to set some conditions to match specific name in query.

Answer (score 0):

Where is WHERE clause in your query in php code? You need to set some conditions to match specific name in query like if you want  to search 'abcd' then your query should be `SELECT * FROM groupdesign WHERE column_name = "abcd"`. This will return records which contanis value "abcd" from your database

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try to resolve it by changing my android code